# condition on filtered value in angular partial (html)

Tags: angularjs

I am stuck on to set url conditionally in `ng-src`. I have created filter that returns parts of string based on which I am fetching logo image but sometimes it may possible that filter returns blank so at that time I want to set my static image as logo.

Please help.

`My approach` **Not working**

```
<img ng-src="{{CU.email | split:'@':1 && 'https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/{{CU.email | split:'@':1}}/images/logo.gif'}}"></img>
```

`Second approach`

```
<img ng-src="https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/{{CU.email | split:'@':1}}/images/logo.gif"></img>
```

it is working but sometimes throws network 404 error as sometimes filter return blank value.

**FILTER**

```
myApp.filter('split',function(){
    return function(str,delimeter,index) {
        str = str || "";
        delimeter = delimeter || ",";

        return str.split(delimeter)[index] || "";

    }
});
```

Comment: yeah, you can't do that due to angular rendering thing. Filter the results in your controller before presenting them in a template.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I was just wondering if there is anything to do this in partials only.